# How to overwrite C-c C-v hotkeys for LaTeX-mode-map?

Tags: key-bindings, latex

Now i use this:

```
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") nil))

(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") 'my-open-file-LaTeX))
```

I DO NOT use Auctex it's just generic LaTeX-mode in emacs.

but there is just no reaction to this, it's still trying to use `'Tex-view`

C-h k C-c C-v prompt:

```
C-c C-v runs the command tex-view (found in latex-mode-map), which is
an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘tex-mode.el’.

It is bound to C-c C-v, <menu-bar> <tex> <tex-view>.

(tex-view)

Preview the last ‘.dvi’ file made by running TeX under Emacs.
This means, made using C-c C-r, C-c C-b or C-c C-f.
The variable ‘tex-dvi-view-command’ specifies the shell command for preview.
You must set that variable yourself before using this command,
because there is no standard value that would generally work.
```

Comment: Are you sure AUCTeX is installed and configured correctly? Type `C-h k C-c C-v` in a latex buffer and post the output.

Comment: @matteol , prompt added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LaTeX-mode-map` is the keymap for `Auctex`. If you want to change a key in the built-in latex mode (i.e., not Auctex), use `latex-mode-map` instead (all lowercase). Note that you don't have to 'unbind' the key first, just the following line should work:

```
(eval-after-load 'tex-mode
  '(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") 'my-open-file-LaTeX))
```

Answer (score 0):

After i install Auctex:

```
(use-package tex
  :defer t
  :ensure auctex
  :config
  (setq TeX-parse-self t); Enable parse on load.
  (setq TeX-auto-save t); Enable parse on save.
  (setq-default TeX-master nil)

  (setq TeX-PDF-mode t)); PDF mode (rather than DVI-mode))
```

it's working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. You said you aren't using Auctex in your question, and this code is probably not doing what you think - there's no `tex` package, and `:ensure` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @Tyler While you are right about the OP confusing if AUCTeX is used or not, this is right on the [`use-package README`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#package-installation) doing: `(use-package tex
  :ensure auctex)`